# Move Duplicate Nodes in the Same Layer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop

In ArcMap 10.1 can I move duplicate nodes in the same layer like I can in MapInfo? I want to click on the place where two or more lines converge and move the endpoints of all the lines to the location where I release the mouse. In MapInfo it is Options > Preferences > Map Window > Editing > Move Duplicate Nodes in the Same Layer > OK.

Comment: If you have a geometric network, did you try [these steps](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/edgdb_11.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS for Desktop has map topology capabilities described in the section "Editing Shared Geometry with Topology".

You must first **[Create a Map Topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000r000000)** which is not the same as a Geodatabase Topology and unlike that is available at all license levels.

Comment: kLewis: That worked! Thanks. You can even select which lines whose endpoints you want to mass move. Cool!

Comment: @PaulKranz It looks like the answer by klewis is what you were after so don't forget to reward him/her by hitting the Accept button.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found that functionality yet in anything made by Esri.  But ETGeoTools has exactly what you want:
[image: ETGeoTools Toolbar]

Find it here:

http://www.ian-ko.com/